# How to get QVBoxLayout to contract QDialog when removing child layouts?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog with a QVBoxLayout controlling its height.

This main QVBoxLayout consists of one or more QVBoxLayout children, followed by some other widgets.  As I add additional QVBoxLayout children, (and/or lower widgets) the dialog box expands to accommodate them - as you would expect, and as I want.

However, when I remove QVBoxLayout children from the parent QVBoxLayout, the dialog box is not resized smaller by the amount equal to the size of the QVBoxLayout that was removed - it just remains the same size with unsightly large blank areas.

How do I achieve the correct dynamic behaviour in QVBoxLayout/QDialog, such that the dialog box is resized properly when child components are removed from the QVBoxLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `mainLayoutPtr->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)` (this will also make the dialog not resizable by user, but it will be able to properly resize when widgets hide/show)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the dialog to be resizeable by the user at times too.  (Something I need to fix to be sensible soon.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make the dialog non-resizable, you can resize it manually after any child is deleted:

```
QApplication::processEvents();
dialog->resize(dialog->sizeHint());
```

Answer (score 0):

`QWidget::adjustSize()` is what you are looking for:

Adjusts the size of the widget to fit its contents.

This function uses sizeHint() if it is valid, i.e., the size hint's width and height are >= 0. Otherwise, it sets the size to the children rectangle that covers all child widgets (the union of all child widget rectangles).

For windows, the screen size is also taken into account. If the sizeHint() is less than (200, 100) and the size policy is expanding, the window will be at least (200, 100). The maximum size of a window is 2/3 of the screen's width and height.

Docs - http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#adjustSize

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on its own. Maybe I'm missing something? I've overridden `sizeHint()` to return an invalid size, and I'm calling `adjustSize()` on the dialog after calling `removeItem` on the QVBoxLayout object for the dialog. All I see though is the remaining items in the layout spaced out to fill the 'hole' created when the item was removed, and the dialog remains the size it was before the item was removed.

Comment: I guess the problem is the QVBoxLayout doesn't shrink when items are removed.  Is there anyway to force that?

Comment: did you try `adjustSize()` your dialog while widgets in that dialog had property `setSizePolicy()` set to `QSizePolicy::Maximum`?